# No GoogleAPI target option for new AVD

Tags: api, google-maps, android-virtual-device

I am following the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview) to get started with MapsAPI in Android, after creating a new project I could not create an AVD with the target as "Google APIs (Google Inc)" as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed a few older fixes on here for previous versions of the API and nothing seemed to work, how ever all that was required was a simple restart of Eclipse. Whilst the AVD manager had been restarted as prompted I had not closed Eclipse totally.